# BeautifulSoup Data Grabbing

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to grab a 4 years hourly data with BeautifulSoup from wunderground.com. However I have some problem, when I used this code. The problem is each hour does not shown only in a line. It is separating 3 line (as in attached). That is hard to study on it when I try to filter the datas. I want to have every single data in one line. Could you help me on it.

My code:

```
import urllib.request as urllib2, re, time
# importing parser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
f = open('weather.txt', 'w')
# Start and end year of simulation
for y in range(2009, 2013):
    # Type the months that you want to extract
# For example for January and February use range(1,3)
    for m in range(1, 13):
#checking for leap years
        for d in range(1,32):
            if y%400 == 0:
                leap = True
            elif y%100 == 0:
                leap = False
            elif y%4 == 0:
                leap = True
            else:
                leap = False
            if (m == 2 and leap and d > 29):
                continue
            elif (m == 2 and d > 28):
                continue
            elif (m in [4, 6, 9, 10] and d > 30):
                continue

            url = "http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/LTBA/" + str(y) + "/" + str(m) + "/" + str(d) + "/DailyHistory.html"
            page = urllib2.urlopen(url)

            #opening the website with Beautiful Soup
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

            # finding section with observation details
            paragList = soup.findAll(id="observations_details")
            counter = 0
            counter_max = 0     # maximum number of columns

            # adding a zero to one digit numbers
            string = ''
            if len(str(m)) < 2:
                mStamp = '0' + str(m)
            else:
                mStamp = str(m)
            if len(str(d)) < 2:
                dStamp = '0' + str(d)
            else:
                dStamp = str(d)

            # time stamp is four digit year, two digit month, and two digit day    
            timestamp = str(y) + mStamp + dStamp
            print(timestamp)

            for i in paragList:

                # writing in text file the header with the name of each column
                headList = i.findAll('th')
                f.write('DATE,')
                for k in headList:
                    h_element = k.text
                    s = str(h_element)
                    f.write(s)
                    f.write(',')
                    counter_max = counter_max + 1
                f.write(' \n')

                # writing in text file each row with data
                tableList = i.findAll('tbody')
                for l in tableList:
                    bodyList = l.findAll('td')
                    for j in bodyList:
                        if counter == 0:
                            f.write(timestamp + ',')
                        if j.string:
                            element = j.text
                            # print (element)
                            s = str(element)
                            f.write(s)
                            f.write(',')
                        else:
                            elementList = j.findAll(j.b) + j.findAll('b')
                            for k in elementList:
                                if k.string:
                                    element = k.text
                                    # print(element)
                                    s = str(element)
                                    f.write(s)
                                    f.write(',')
                        counter = counter + 1
                        if counter == counter_max:
                            # print
                            # print("************************")
                            # print("**** NEXT RECORD *******")
                            # print("**** *******************")
                            f.write('\n')
                            counter = 0
            # print ("\n")
            # print("**** NEXT YEAR *******")


f.close()
```

Example output:

[image]

Comment: Can you maybe reduce your problem to a minimal working example?  Right now it's not clear where/what the problem is.  Right now it seems like you're having trouble formatting output (or parsing input?), both of which can be solved by studying corresponding documentations.

Comment: I think it is about being .text formating. I have been doing research for a solution. However there are no at all.

Comment: A lot of times `.text` will give you a string that contains lots of unnecessary whitespaces. You can do `.text.strip()`, which will trim those whitespaces.

Comment: user21398 thank you for your comment. It works!

Comment: Note that data mining is analysis, not collection. Your question belongs to [tag:web-scraping] instead.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! Anony-Mousse I will consider your comment. Have a good day